Navigator.pushReplacement after next screen still has back button, the new screen overrides on last screen
I want to navigate to next screen then do not back to any screen, but when I use Navigator.pushReplacement my app has back button. I mean, arrow back key still work. I want to go to next screen totally, and no back.
Hope anyone help me.
This is my code
return BlocProvider<PostBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => postBloc..add(CreatePostStartEvent()),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: BlocConsumer<PostBloc, PostState>(
          listener: (context, state) async {
            if (state is PostCreationSuccessState) {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Posts()));
            }
          },
      ...


If you need to clear all screens in the navigation stack and push a new one in Flutter, you can use the Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil method. This will remove all existing routes and push the specified route as the new one.
   Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/home',
              (_) => false,
            );


Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true): This accesses the navigator of the root context.
.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false): This method removes all the routes until the given predicate returns true. The predicate (Route<dynamic> route) => false always returns false, ensuring that all routes are removed. Then, it pushes the new route specified by the name '/home'.
This approach is useful when you want to reset the navigation stack and start a fresh with a new screen.


You can refer to this other post on StackOverflow that explains how to delete the Routes list so you don't go back : Flutter remove all routes
There's also go_router, which is pretty easy to use for navigating your application.

Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/second');

This method pops the current route and pushes a new named route.

Wrap the PopScope widget around the Posts() widget
class Posts extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  child: Scaffold(
    
  ),
);
}
}

Then under Posts appBar…
 appBar: AppBar(
 // add this line to remove the back arrow
automaticallyImplyLeading: false,                
),

